# Excel 2010: How to search postcode column for given code, to map fetch suburb from next column

Tags: excel, vba

So we have a 2-column cell-range with postcodes in one column & suburb names in the other. One postcode area can map to multiple suburbs.

We need to fill-in a survey data worksheet with correct suburb, based on each record's postcode (othere's one record's data per worksheet row).

Ideally, we'd do this while data is being input into the larger worksheet, but we can leave suburbs empty & later fill them in, based on postcode.

In cases where a postcode maps to multiple suburbs, user input (with the row's data form in-hand) is required. The user would be shown a list of suburbs & choose the one appearing on the form).

User already has data form in-hand during input cycle, so, this is a preferred time to add in suburb, after user eliminates ambiguity.

Can someone help with code fragments to do this. (It's for a non-profit coomunity food store.)

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` function (non-vba) will do what you want for the first part.  You'd need some VBA to set dynamic validation lists for the second part (where a postcode maps to multiple suburbs).

Answer (score 0):

Modify my code to fit your form, the Function returns an array. There might be better ways but this is what I have at the moment.

```
Function FindSuburbs(sPostcode As String) As Variant
    Dim oRngFirst As Range, oRngSearch As Range, aSuburbs As Variant, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A") ' Change ActiveSheet and the Column as needed
        Set oRngSearch = .Find(sPostcode)
        If oRngSearch Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set oRngFirst = oRngSearch
        i = 0
        aSuburbs = Array()
        ' Look for results
        Do
            If Not oRngSearch Is Nothing Then
                ReDim Preserve aSuburbs(i)
                aSuburbs(i) = oRngSearch.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Stores the Suburb name which is on the next column
                i = i + 1
            End If
            Set oRngSearch = .Find(sPostcode, After:=oRngSearch)
            ' Stop Searching if it is the First Searched Result
        Loop While Not oRngSearch Is Nothing And oRngSearch.Address <> oRngFirst.Address
    End With
    FindSuburbs = aSuburbs
End Function

Sub SO_18908132() ' For Testing
    Dim sPostCode as String
    sPostCode = "Post Code to Search"
    Debug.Print sPostCode & ": " & Join(FindSuburbs(sPostCode), ", ")
End Sub
```